# Magento 2.3.0 - Newsletter subscription message not on homepage

Tags: magento2, newsletter, magento2.3.0, messages, alert

When I submit the newsletter subscription form on the homepage, the page will reload but no message will be shown. When i go to an other page the message is visible for 8 seconds and fades away (that's okay).

But how can i get the message also visible on the homepage, I prefer beneath the input field where you fill in your emailaddress.

Can someone help me with that?

Regards,

Comment: what have you tried? are you familiar with magento2 layout.xml files?